# Right Click PopupMenus in Java

Tags: java, menu, click

```
im trying to get right click menus to come up when they control right click in a JPanel. I researched a bit and was able to develop the code, but for some reason the isPopUpTrigger returns false, any ideas? Thanks!

else if(arg0.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3 )
            {
                if(controlIsPressed){
                    class PopUpDemo extends JPopupMenu {
                        JMenuItem anItem;
                        public PopUpDemo(){
                            anItem = new JMenuItem("Click Me!");
                            add(anItem);
                        }
                    }
                    if(arg0.isPopupTrigger()){
                        PopUpDemo menu = new PopUpDemo();
                        menu.show(arg0.getComponent(), arg0.getX(), arg0.getY());
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method in `MouseListener` are you calling this in? Depending on which OS, it may be triggered by `mousePressed` or `mouseReleased` so you need to call this from both of those methods.

Comment: Yep that was it, I only had it in moused pressed, but now I am encountering another issue, Im currently trying to make a map editor for another application, and this is actually a runnable application running at 30 FPS, so my popup only comes up for a few seconds then flickers on and off somewhat slowly, any idea how i can get it to work in a running JPanel.

Comment: Without seeing more code, it's tough to tell. Be sure you're performing all GUI related applications in the event dispatch thread. Not doing so is a common cause of flickers. If you need more info, you should post a new question with some details/code.